# Matching Tables Together

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I've been working with the sDom and can't get it to cooperate. I'm just a place where I'm stuck. I have a table that displays as an example below but I"m trying to get it to end up looking like this somehow.

http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/manager/index2.html

http://datatables.net/styling/themes/redmond

Comment: In your example jQuery is not loaded correctly. Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  table in the example  is initialized like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {             
   $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"   
   } );
} )
```

so you don't need to set sDom. In any case there is an error in your code, jquery is not loaded correctly

Comment: I have no idea but its not even showing the length or filter parts. http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/sLyeP/

Comment: The page in the example is just a template layout page that I got when I downloaded the free template I have my own tables.

Comment: I didn't. I was just checking it because I used it but I still don't have it working as well as I can't even get the jsfiddle to show correctly.

Comment: In your fiddle you didn't initialize the datatable, didn't load jquery UI and didn't include the jQuery CSS. Rember that you need to include jquery UI to style the table as you want. look here http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/sLyeP/1/

Comment: I did include this var oTable = $('#templatesPageList').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"   
   } ); its in my pagination.js file that's included.

Comment: Ah ok, for some reason it didn't work, maybe the problem was that you didn't include jQuery UI and the relative CSS file

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1982/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-nicola-peluchetti)

Comment: I was hoping I could show you the live version of what I have now working. Could you come to chat for a minute?